# Refine Data From MYSQL database with PHP and Ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a php page in which at left sidebar i have a query form and at right sidebar i have space to display result when query form is submitted without refreshing the whole page, Problem is that the whole page get refreshed every time i have tried many ajax function but no one could help me.
I want to display like this-
http://www.makaan.com/jaipur-property/residential-property-for-sale-in-jaipur/search-properties
In this Page At LeftSidebar when i click any checkbox it display result without refresh whole page.

Please Help Me, Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide some sample code, show us what you've got so far. There are enough samples available online on how to update parts of a page using PHP and AJAX

Comment: And please use proper punctuation and text formatting (where applicable) as well … the “question” in its current format is hard to read resp. understand.

Answer (score 0):

you should catch a submit event and tell him, in case you make in with jQuery, 
something like

```
$(form).submit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
}
```